Azure API Management Referencing Query Parameters
I have created an Azure API Management Service to connect to the API of Autotask.
Now I want to Query all tickets of a user, but I have to retrieve the tickets with pagination, as the tool I'm trying to make doesn't Support as much Data at once.
The Autotask API when using pagination returns a "nextPageUrl" that u'll have to call with the next API call.
Because of that, I have added a Query parameter to my API Mng and in the inbound policies i want to add a policy that changes the Backend URL to the given nextPageUrl if given. But if there is no URL given, it should just keep its current url.
So here I have the query parameter:

And this is the Part i added in the inbound policies:
<choose>
        <when condition="@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault('nextPageUrl', '')))">
            <set-backend-service base-url="@{context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault('nextPageUrl', '')}" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-backend-service base-url="https://webservices.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/v1.0/Tickets/query" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>

i am no Pro in this matter, i tried to solve it with GPT and some research but this doesnt seem to work as i want it to. Does anybody know how i can properly write the policy?

is nextPageUrl  a part of Autotask API because you have added query parameter that means nextPageUrl is present as a query parameter in Autotask API?

If Autotask API returns nextPageUrl then you need to store it in a variable and use the given policy to meet your requirement.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="nextPageUrl" value="{nextPageUrl}" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)context.Variables["nextPageUrl"]))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("nextPageUrl"))" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://webservices.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/v1.0/Tickets/query" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
</policies>



If Autotask API contains nextPageUrl like <Autotask API>?nextPageUrl then in this case, you can use the query parameter to fetch nextPageUrl from URL and use it in your policy.
For query parameter approach, you need to pass nextPageUrl as shown below

You should have below policy for query parameter.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("nextPageUrl", "")))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("nextPageUrl", ""))" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://webservices.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/v1.0/Tickets/query" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
</policies>

